# What are the scoring mechanics for breaking bubbles in Pang (aka Buster Bros.)?

Tags: pang

I'm trying to understand the scoring mechanics for breaking bubbles in the original 1989 arcade version of *Pang* (aka *Buster Bros.* or *Pomping World*) because I'm implementing it myself for fun in PyGame. I don't have my own copy of the game. From [these](https://youtu.be/UyhP6uLk9Fg?t=94) [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aOTSD_BhWHk) [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJwdhhESPS8), I've figured out that, in descending order of size, bubbles are normally worth 50, 100, 150, and 200 points when broken.

Sometimes, however, a 2x, 4x, or 8x multiplier applies. In these cases only, the total score for that bubble appears on screen where the bubble was burst.

My question is, what are the mechanics that govern the multiplier? I need to know what triggers it, what stops it, and to which bubbles it applies.

Things I've observed:

- The multiplier starts after at least 2 pops and as many as 9.
- Sometimes it will be on for one bubble, off for the next, then back on for the one after that.
- The multiplier always starts at 2x, then 4x, then 8x, and stays at 8x.
- If any bubble doesn't get the multiplier, the next one starts at 2x again.

That's not enough information to create an algorithm.

Answer (score 5):

I've figured it out, and for the sake of completeness, here's everything I know about the scoring mechanics in Pang. I believe the only thing missing is the algorithm for the number of points for completing the game.

**Bubbles**
In descending order of size, bubbles are worth 50, 100, 150 and 200 points when broken by the player's weapons. If they're broken any other way, like by an animal or by touching the player, no points are awarded.

If a player has a streak of breaking the same size bubble, the bubble's points are multiplied by 2, 4 or 8 if the streak is 2, 3 or 4 bubbles long, respectively. Streaks longer than 4 are all multiplied by 8. So for example, your first bubble of the smallest size is worth 200 points, the second 400, the third 800, and the fourth 1600. The fifth and beyond are all worth 1600. The streak ends when the player bursts a different sized bubble. It does not end if the player shoots without hitting any bubbles, nor if an animal bursts a bubble.

**Bricks**
Destructible bricks, including invisible ones, give 500 points each when destroyed.

**Animals**

| type | points |
| --- | --- |
| condor | 500 |
| red crab | 200 |
| hermit crab | 50 |
| hummingbird | 150 |
| owl | 200 |

**Items**
Items that drop from popped bubbles or destroyed bricks are worth 100 points each.

**Food items**

| stage | type | points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cherries | 500 |
| 2 | lemon | 1,000 |
| 3 | banana | 2,000 |
| 4 | orange | 3,000 |
| 5 | watermelon | 4,000 |
| 6 | pineapple | 5,000 |
| 7 | grapes | 6,000 |
| 8 | apple | 7,000 |
| 9 | strawberry | 8,000 |
| 10 | honeydew | 9,000 |
| 11 | pickle | 10,000 |
| 12 | eggplant | 12,000 |
| 13 | tomato | 14,000 |
| 14 | squash | 16,000 |
| 15 | carrot | 18,000 |
| 16 | corn | 20,000 |
| 17 | green pepper | 22,000 |
| 18 | radish | 24,000 |
| 19 | mushroom | 26,000 |
| 20 | bean | 28,000 |
| 21 | hamburger | 30,000 |
| 22 | hotdog | 33,000 |
| 23 | wiener on a stick | 36,000 |
| 24 | doughnut | 39,000 |
| 25 | chicken drumstick | 42,000 |
| 26 | french fries | 45,000 |
| 27 | shrimp nigiri | 48,000 |
| 28 | cake | 50,000 |

From stage 29 on, all food is cake, and it alternates between being worth 48,000 and 50,000.

If the player shoots the food as it's falling rather than touching it, it's worth one level less, so for instance, shooting a shrimp nigiri is worth 45,000, rather than 48,000.

**Time remaining**
At the end of each stage, the player receives 100x the number remaining on the clock. If it's the last of the three stages in that location, the player receives double the time bonus.

**Astronaut**
Shooting the astronaut is worth 10,000 points.

**Completing the game**
The only three values I have for completion points are:

- 904,400
- 904,700
- 804,800